# Build fails after swapping to pnpm: RollupError: Unexpected character '\x7F' (caused by parse error in node-canvas / pdf.js)

Tags: svelte, pdf.js, rollupjs, pnpm, node-canvas

Thanks in advance for any help.

TL;DR: I have a parse error at build time bubbling from `node-canvas` and `pdf.js`. This is caused by Rollup reading the `canvas.node` binary, which shouldn't even be in the build output...

Is there any way to mark an individual module (`pdf.js`) for browser resolution? Or any other solution/work-around to allow `pdf.js` to work with `pnpm`?

I believe that [the accepted solution in the `node-canvas` repo](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1504) will not work here as the SvelteKit build should produce outputs for both node and the browser.

---

I've swapped my package manager to pnpm for a SvelteKit app.

It has been great when running in dev mode, but the build is now failing with these raw logs:

```
node_modules/.pnpm/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js (1950:23)
Use of eval in "node_modules/.pnpm/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js" is strongly discouraged as it poses security risks and may cause issues with minification.

# ... succesful build outputs
.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js                                                                                                    104.13 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/room/_room_/_page@room.svelte.js                                                              125.46 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/media-handlers.js                                                                                    145.42 kB

Run npm run preview to preview your production build locally.

> Using @sveltejs/adapter-node
error during build:
RollupError: Unexpected character '' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
    at error (file:///home/oscarhermoso/Git/org-repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.28.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2245:30)
    at Module.error (file:///home/oscarhermoso/Git/org-repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.28.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13674:16)
    at Module.tryParse (file:///home/oscarhermoso/Git/org-repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.28.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:14405:25)
    at Module.setSource (file:///home/oscarhermoso/Git/org-repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.28.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:14006:39)
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (file:///home/oscarhermoso/Git/org-repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.28.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24526:20)
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

The error is bubbling from [this rollup.js `error()` function](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/blob/4398d4dc0b2934e03d60a538b45046c817e080c7/src/utils/logs.ts#L32) which is hiding some of the info.

After editing node_modules to `console.trace` on the `base`, we have additional info:

```
Trace: {
  cause: SyntaxError: Unexpected character '' (1:0) # <-- contains U+007f, invisible
  # ...
  code: 'PARSE_ERROR',
  id: '/home/oscarhermoso/Git/org-repo/node_modules/.pnpm/canvas@2.11.2/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node',
  message: "Unexpected character '\x7F' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)",
  frame: '1: \x7FELF\x02\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x'
   # ...
}
# ...

# Listing each of the ids in the trace: 

/home/oscarhermoso/Git/org-repo/node_modules/.pnpm/canvas@2.11.2/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
/home/oscarhermoso/Git/org-repo/node_modules/.pnpm/canvas@2.11.2/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js
/home/oscarhermoso/Git/org-repo/node_modules/.pnpm/canvas@2.11.2/node_modules/canvas/index.js
/home/oscarhermoso/Git/org-repo/node_modules/.pnpm/canvas@2.11.2/node_modules/canvas/lib/image.js
/home/oscarhermoso/Git/org-repo/node_modules/.pnpm/canvas@2.11.2/node_modules/canvas/lib/canvas.js
/home/oscarhermoso/Git/org-repo/node_modules/.pnpm/canvas@2.11.2/node_modules/canvas/lib/context2d.js
/home/oscarhermoso/Git/org-repo/node_modules/.pnpm/canvas@2.11.2/node_modules/canvas/lib/pattern.js
/home/oscarhermoso/Git/org-repo/node_modules/.pnpm/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js
```

My interpretation is that Rollup is evaluating the `canvas-node` binary at build time. This is unfortunate, because it should not be needed at all, the `pdf.js` package is only being bundled for the browser.

I am also not sure why this behaviour would be caused by swapping the package manager from `npm` to `pnpm` though.

I've hit a wall trying to resolve or workaround this issue, outside of swapping back to `npm` so any advice would be sincerely appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out.

I'm only using `pdf.js` in the browser, so I'm able to exclude `node-canvas` by marking it as an optional dependency and then skipping it in CI/CD.

There may have also an issue/incompatibility with `pdf-js` version `^3.9.179`

#### Steps to resolve:

1. Add `"canvas": "*"` to `optionalDependencies` in `package.json`
2. Update `pdfds-dist` to latest version (currently `v3.10.111`)
3. `rm -rf node_modules`
4. `pnpm install` to update the `pnpm-lock.yaml` file
5. Test with `pnpm install --no-optional` followed by `pnpm build`
6. Update your CI/CD pipeline or Dockerfile to include `pnpm install --no-optional` instead of `pnpm install`.